# HTML formatting with styles -- Just give up and use tables?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'll preface this question by stating I have historically used tables for my HTML formatting and am fairly good at getting it to look the way I'd like...  I am aware that tables are meant for "tabular data" and not formatting.  I always get a bit frustrated when I try to do it the "right way", so today I am seeking some help.

```
<div style="width: 90%;">

  <div style="width: 50%; height: 75px; vertical-align: middle; float: left;">
    <a href="a.html" style="margin: auto 0px auto 0px">
      <img src="../../images/red_arrow_50.png" alt="a" width="50" height="50" style="border-width: 0px;" />
    </a>
    <a href="a.html" style="margin: auto 0px auto 0px;">A Link</a>                        
  </div>

  <div style="width: 50%; float: right;">
    <a href="b.html">B Link</a>                        
  </div>

</div>
```

As you can see from my attempts above, I'd like for the image link and the 2 text links to all line up along the same horizontal line (i.e. text links at the center of the image).  Depending on how wide the parent div is I'd like the A img/link and B link a reasonable distance from one another.  I'd also like for the divs with the "float: left" and "float: right" styles to *not* extend south beyond the border of the parent div (for some reason it is doing that to me in firefox with the above code).

Please help set me straight?  Am I the only one who finds "the right way" of formatting things to be a big pain in the rear?  I'm hoping I'm missing something big that if corrected will get me going down the right path.

===============

Update, thanks for the comments, I went to jsfiddle and fiddled a table-based solution:

```
   <table style="width: 90%; margin: 0px auto 0px auto;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%;"><a href="a.htm"><img src="http://www.chemfindit.com/img/search_icon.jpg" alt="A" width="50" height="50" style="border-width: 0px; vertical-align: middle;" /></a><a href="a.htm" style="margin: auto 0px auto 0px; vertical-align: middle;" >A-Link</a></td>
            <td style=""><a href="b.htm"><img src="http://www.chemfindit.com/img/search_icon.jpg" alt="B" width="50" height="50" style="border-width: 0px; vertical-align:middle;" /></a><a href="b.htm" style="margin: auto 0px auto 0px; vertical-align: middle;" >B-Link</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Yields the desired layout:

[image: Desired Layout]

I think it must be my misunderstanding/usage of floats and positions that always stings me when I try div-based layouts.

Comment: Could you put an image of what you're after up? It'll make helping loads easier. Ta

Comment: Or a link to a fiddle would be good too. Btw, CSS may be simple but it's definitely not easy to get it just right.

Comment: As the saying goes, "If you need a hammer, use a hammer..." Seriously, I've found complex div based layouts a headache, though I've found sites like http://www.positioniseverything.net/ helpful to figure out div based layouts. (Long as you stay away from deeply nested tables I think you'll be OK...wow, I'm showing my age!)

Comment: There is certainly a place for just doing your own thing... but if you don't use standard development procedures, you can cause major problems for those who come behind you... think IE

Comment: "Am I the only one who finds "the right way" of formatting things to be a big pain in the rear?" No, you're definitively not the only one. We are at least two ... :)

Comment: Added a table-based markup that looks good to me and an image of what I'm after

Comment: Is it always going to just be two links or do you want scope for more in the row?

Comment: Just the two, but knowing how to apply it to x would be nice.  I'm looking to learn and thank you all for the help ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I'd do it like this - http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/nWNPm/7/

```
.magLink {
        list-style: none; 
        height: 50px;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 50px 0 0;
}

.magLink li {
        float: left;
        height: 50px;
        display: table;
}

.magLink li a {
        height: 50px;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
}


<ul class="magLink">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.whg.uk.com/Image/Magnifying_glass_1.gif" width="50" height="50" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link A</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can just copy the `<ul>` to have more than one. Just adjust the right margin to space them out how ever you want. I've set up examples of single link, multiple links and links with extra styling for in in the JSFIddle.

**EDIT:**

JSFiddle's running pretty badly so here's an image of the output in case it's not working.

[image]

Vertical alignment can be a real pain in CSS but tables for layout have had their day man. Let them live out their days being used for tabular data in peace.

Comment: "tables for layout have had their day man" ha - I'm trying -- Thanks for the examples!

Comment: No worries. When I have to make changes to sites I did using tables I want to murder myself.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>From what I can tell, your "floaters" are extending beyond the parent div because you have two 50% widths inside of a 90%. Try setting them both to 45%.</strike> Then set a `class` or an `id` on your two floater containers, set them to `position:relative`, set both your link and img within each floating `div` to `position:absolute`, and use `left, right, top,` and `bottom` to move them into place (the img and link will be confined to the relatively positioned parent `div`). Does this help?

**Edit**

```
<div style="width: 90%;">

<div style="width: 50%; height: 75px; vertical-align: middle; float: left; position:relative;">
<a href="a.html" style="margin: auto 0px auto 0px;">
<img src="http://www.chemfindit.com/img/search_icon.jpg" alt="a" width="50" height="50" style="border-   width: 0px;" />
</a>
<a href="a.html" style="margin: auto 0px auto 0px; position:absolute; top:15px;">A Link</a>                        
</div>

<div style="width: 50%; float: right; height:75px; vertical-align: middle; position:relative;">
<a href="b.html"  style="margin: auto 0px auto 0px; position:absolute; left:50px; top:15px;">B Link</a>
<img src="http://www.chemfindit.com/img/search_icon.jpg" alt="b" width="50" height="50" style="border-width: 0px;" />                        
</div>

</div>
```

That is the code equivalent to your table layout.
I would have used jsfiddle but I got a 504 error... probably didn't hold my mouth right. :)

Comment: They'll be 50% of the parent container, not the page.

Comment: Ok. I think I had a problem similar to this a while back and that is how I fixed it, but I may not be remembering correctly...

Comment: it may be a matter of just setting the parent element to `position:relative`